# Copying files from directories having spaces in its name

Tags: command-line, cp

This is what I tried.

```
inputFile=$(zenity --file-selection --title "Test" --text "Please select the file for analysis." | sed -e "s/ /\\\ /g")
```

I did the `sed` operation to replace white spaces with a `\` and a whitespace to make the copying command to work. Then from the Zenity file selection GUI I have chosen a file so that the value inside `inputFile` is `/home/username/Documents/Learning\ and\ Development/testfile.txt`.

Now when I try to copy this file to my working directory with

```
cp $inputFile .
```

Still it returns the error,

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/user/Documents/Learning\\’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘and\\’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘Development/WhatsApp.apk’: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to bypass this? Actually I am writing a program. So I don't want to tell the users to rename their folder names to avoid spaces.

Comment: How about `cp "$inputFile" .`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easily you can do the trick, enclose by double quotes:

```
cp "$inputFile" /destination/
```

Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, Read more: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

Comment: Omg! It worked. I burned hell lot of time on this. My bad :( By the way, I had to remove the `sed` operation I did in order to work this :)

Comment: Works like a charm just add a " to encapsulate the path. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 5):

you can add * where the space appeared and the copy can be done
like

```
 cp  /home/user/users*tst.txt  /home/user/Downloads
```

where you want to copy users tst.txt to Downloads folder from home folder

Comment: instead of * you can use ? too